# How can I enter multiline methods in the interactive Io interpreter?

Tags: iolanguage

I am trying the following sample from [7 Languages in 7 Weeks](http://pragprog.com/book/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks):

```
Object ancestors := method(
    prototype := self proto
        if(prototype != Object,
            writeln("Slots of ", prototype type, "\n---------------")
            prototype slotNames foreach(slotName, writeln(slotName))
            writeln
            prototype ancestors))
```

If I put the code in a file with the rest of the example (e.g. `animals.io`) and execute it via the command line `io animals.io` then it works as expected.

However, if I attempt to type the method in manually and execute it for any object, I get the following error:

```
Exception: Object does not respond to 'prototype'
---------
Object prototype                     Command Line 1
Object ancestors                     Command Line 1
```

Is it possible to enter this multi-line method via the interactive interpreter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use semicolon as a line separator in REPL.

```
Object ancestors := method(
    prototype := self proto;
        if(prototype != Object,
            writeln("Slots of ", prototype type, "\n---------------");
            prototype slotNames foreach(slotName, writeln(slotName));
            writeln;
            prototype ancestors))
```

Answer (score 1):

While the Io REPL allows you to enter multiline statements [1], it unfortunately seems to just concatenate the lines together :(

```
Io> Object getSlot("ancestors")
==> method(
    prototype := self proto if(prototype != Object, writeln("Slots of ", prototype type, "\n---------------") prototype slotNames foreach(slotName, writeln(slotName)) writeln prototype ancestors)
)
```

*[1] - You will probably need ReadLine installed on your OS*

Comment: Ah ok. Maybe I can submit a bug report :) At least it's not something weird happening just on my machine.

Comment: I seem to recall that readline/multilines in the REPL as had problems in the past and it was often switched off by default (because occasionally the REPL would sporadically die).